# retrieve a floating point value from mongo db using cpp

Tags: c++, mongodb

Here is my code knowing that **test**  is floating point in a collection in mongodb database. I don't know what to use to retrieve it. worth to mention I can access name with the following line

```
name  = tmpArray[i].embeddedObject().getStringField("name");


string test;    
vector <BSONElement> testArray;
BSONObj bsnobj = cursor->next();
bsnobj.getObjectField("here").elems(tmpArray);
for(int i=0; i<testArray.size(); i++){
    test  = testArray[i].embeddedObject().getObjectField("test").toString();
    cout << test is: <<test << endl ;

}
```

This results in

```
test is: {}
```

This is how data looks like

```
{

"here" : [
    {
        "name" : "x",
        "source" : "xx",
        "test" : 1,

    },
    {
        "name" : "y",
        "source" : "yy",
        "test" : 1,

    }
],

"if" : true

}
```

Comment: What's the structure look like of the document?

Comment: I would have thought it was `numberDouble()`.

Comment: Still, I would have thought you should use `numberDouble` for the `"test"` field instead of `toString`.

Comment: @WiredPrairie error: ‘class mongo::BSONObj’ has no member named ‘numberDouble’

Comment: `getField("test").numberDouble()`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks it worked , may be you can right it as an answer then I can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

```
test  = testArray[i].embeddedObject().getObjectField("test").toString();
```

You were using `getObjectField` which returns another named BSON object. As you want a double, you'll need to use `getField` instead. Secondly, to fetch the value of the `test` field as a double, you can use the function `numberDouble`.

So, you could change your code to:

```
auto test  = testArray[i].embeddedObject().getField("test").numberDouble();
```

In the sample data you provided, the result would be:

```
test is: 1.0
```